# What does "Capture Heap" do in the developer menu?

Tags: react-native

[image: Screenshot]

When I click it, the developer menu disappears both nothing happens.  Googling for this options has turned up nothing useful.  In fact, the first google hit ends up being the strings.xml file on github that contains the string.

Comment: Did you have any luck finding out what this feature is used for?

Comment: When I press the option I see `E/JSCHeapCapture: No JSC registered` in logcat so I assume there is some JS configuration required

Answer (score 0):

If the JSC build that you are running was compiled with the flag `WITH_FB_MEMORY_PROFILING` (my guess is you have to compile it for yourself) then there will be a method exposed to Javascript `nativeCaptureHeap(output_filepath)`.

In order to tie it all together and make the button work, you need to have a heap dump provider on the Javascript side. The provider is a module with a specific name `HeapCapture`. When you press the button, it loads the JS dump provider, and calls `captureHeap(path)` on it.

The dump file will be output to `<path>/capture.json`

An example of one that I found:

```js
'use strict';

var HeapCapture = {
  captureHeap: function captureHeap(path) {
    var error = null;
    try {
      global.nativeCaptureHeap(path);
      console.log('HeapCapture.captureHeap succeeded: ' + path);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('HeapCapture.captureHeap error: ' + e.toString());
      error = e.toString();
    }
    require('NativeModules').JSCHeapCapture.captureComplete(path, error);
  }
};

module.exports = HeapCapture;
```